# How to process Report Map and read key presses from bluetooth keyboard?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, keyboard-events, esp32, hid

I am stuck with a project of a BLE Keyboard to PS2 adapter with the ESP32 microcontroller. For the BLE part, I use the [NimBLE library](https://github.com/h2zero/NimBLE-Arduino). My bluetooth keyboard is a Microsoft Surface Ergonomic Keyboard. I have no previous experience with BLE.

These are the services and their characteristics of the bluetooth keyboard:

```
 0x1800: Generic Access
      Characteristics:
      0x2a00: Device Name
      0x2a01: Appearance
      0x2a04: Peripherial Preferred Connection Parameters
    0x1801: Generic Attribute
    0x180a: Device Information
      Characteristics:
      0x2a29: Manifacturer Name
      0x2a50: PNP Id
    0x180f: Battery Service
      Characteristic:
      0x2a19: Battery Level
    0x1812: HID Service
      Characteristics:
      0x2a4e: Protocol Mode
      0x2a4d: Report
      0x2a4b: Report Map
      0x2a22: Boot Keyboard Input Report
      0x2a32: Boot Keyboard Output Report
      0x2a4a: HID Information
      0x2a4c: HID Control Point
```

After I find it and pair it by entering the PIN, I can successfully read the battery level and receive notifications when it changes, so I got the pairing, notification registering and reading values from characteristics alright.

Now I want obviously to read key presses. I take the "Report Map" characteristic of the HID service and read its values that describe the report. Meaning of the values [here in section E.6](https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/documents/hid1_11.pdf).

```
0x05, 0x01 -> Usage Page (Generic Desktop)
0x09, 0x06 -> Usage (Keyboard)
0xA1, 0x01 -> Collection (Application)
0x85, 0x01 -> ???
0x15       -> Logical Minimum? (0)
```

**I don't know what to do with this information.** I assume I will need this later to interpret the incoming reports of key presses. However, I don't know how to receive them.

I continue with the "Report" characteristic because I assume this is the place where key presses come in?
I read the characteristic's value: It has the handle 0x0047 and the value 0x78. I register for notifications.
Then I get the same characteristic a second time, now it has the handle 0x0016, same value and a 2902 descriptor with value 1 (meaning it is in report mode and not in boot mode). I register again for notifications, but I receive no notification when I press keys.

**How do I read reports from the device?** They obviously do not come as notifications.

Comment: What do you mean by "I cannot register for notifications."? Are you getting errors? What errors in that case?

Comment: Hi, thank you for the question. Before I register a callback function for notifications, I checked with NimBLEs function BLERemoteCharacteristic::canNotify if I can. That is a test of the GATT structure's properties for the appropriate bit. I skipped that test now and try to register anyways: It works, I updated my question. Should I receive notifications on key presses? I just want to know in which direction I should go.